# Is there a way to temporarily 'ignore' keyframes on a specific frame?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

In the Dope Sheet I have numerous keyframes. Is there a way to temporarily "ignore" the keyframes on a specific frame so they aren't considered when running the animation?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a duplicate. I'm looking for a way to disable the entire column of keyframes, or ignore them.

Comment: I can only go by what is in the question. I have edited it to be clearer about what you mean.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the keyframes in the column. You can always restore them with *Ctrl* + *Z*, when you're not happy with the result.

Comment: @PaulGonet Blender counts changing the current frame as an action, which you would also have to undo, so if you moved in the timeline a lot you could potentially run out of undo steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't disable them as such, but you can move them out of the way.

Select the keyframes you want to 'disable' and ensure the current frame is frame 0. Press <kbd>S</kbd> to Scale and type -1. This will scale using the current frame (zero) as the origin and swap the keyframe to the other side of the axis - so, for example, keyframes on frame 20 will be moved to frame -20. This will move them outside of the normal range of animated frames and effectively disable them (provided you have a keyframe at the start of the animation to set the initial state).

**Enabled - the keyframe is in it's 'normal' position**

[image: enabled]

[image: enabled - animation]

**Disabled - the keyframe has been moved to the opposite side of the axis**

[image: disabled]

[image: disabled - animation]

To 're-enable' the keyframes you can simply repeat the same action to mirror it back to the positive side of the axis (ie, frame -20 scaled by -1 becomes frame 20 again).

Comment: Very smart and helpful solution!